# How can I delete all inactive AWS Batch jobs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I have old **AWS Batch jobs** that are deregistered. In the console, they show up under `AWS Batch` > `Job definitions`, when setting the filter to `INACTIVE`.

Can I delete those?

The analogous process for **AWS ECR** is "active job" -> deregister -> "inactive" -> delete -> (gone). Is there something similar for AWS Batch? I would love to clean up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is not an API action to remove inactive job definitions. Job definitions are permanently deleted after 180 days.